# Connecting OneDrive to Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, onedrive, intellij-plugin, intellij-14, intellij-13

It appears my OneDrive isn't available on Intellij. When creating or saving new projects, only folders within my local disk (C:) are available. No parent or sisters, just C:

Are there steps required to have access to onedrive on IntelliJ?

I downloaded .exe rather than .zip, maybe that's it?

Thanks

screenshot of IntelliJ's file explorer compared to my PC's file explorer. Only available location in IntelliJ is local disk.
[IntelliJ File Trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymgj5.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of how your File Chooser looks like on IntelliJ IDEA? OneDrive files located on `C:/OneDrive` directory by default.

Comment: Make also sure you check it with the version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/  IDEA 13 and 13 versions are too old and may not know OneDrive specifics.

Comment: `Desktop` directory is not located in the root of the `C:` drive. It is usually located under `C:/Users/<user name>/Desktop`. You can see the full path to it in Explorer when you open this directory and select on the path in Explorer window. What path do you see there?